# Hide row when result of spesific column is null in Datatable automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, laravel-5.1

i want to ask about how to hide one row, in example one row contain 10 columns, the first and second column is filled with right value, but third until end value is null, i want to hide the row that have the condition like that. i've tried to make filter before its rendered but not work, please help. This is my code

```
oTable = $('#data').DataTable({
   "ordering":true,
   "columns": [
   {data: 'no', name: 'no'},
   {data: 'number', name: 'number'},
   {data: 'action', name: 'action'},
   {data: 'status', name: 'status'},],});
   //Used For Call Data (AJAX)

<table id="data" class="table table-striped table-bordered display" style="width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll" >
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 25px">No</th>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Action<br></th>
    <th>Current Status</th>
  </tr>
 //Used to make table

public function getData(Request $request)
{
    return Datatables::of(\App\Model\SomeModel::query())->make(true);
}
```

Thank you. Any idea and help will much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is in the backend PHP, ASP etc if you have.
But if you just have a HTML code you need to do an each in all tr tags  and take the element that you want to validate.

Example:

```
jQuery("#data tr").each(function(){
  my_tr = jQuery(this);
  my_td= my_tr.find("td.my_validate_td_class");
  if(my_td.val() == ""){
    my_tr.hide();
  }
})
```

Comment: yes you can see my laravel controller backend, and i've updated my code kindly take review of my code

Comment: i've done. the solutions is trying to get not null data in spesific columns from laravel backend, thankyou for inspiring me